# Regex scraper challenge

Tags: php, html, regex

I am building a php data miner (scraper)
I have this html line:

```
<label class='area'>
  <font class='bg_info' onmouseover="land_convert_txt(this,3067)" onmouseout='tooltip_hide()'>
   3,067 Sq. Ft.
  </font>
```

how to setup my regex to extract the area value only?

this is my function:

```
function extract_regex($subject, $regex, $index = 1)
{
    preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $matches);
    if (count($matches[$index]))
    {
        if (count($matches[$index]) == 1)
        {
            return trim($matches[$index][0]);
        }
        return $matches[$index];        
    }
    return '';
}
```

`(this,3067)` keep changing!

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Why not simply strip_tags()?

Comment: $article['area'] = extract_regex($html, '/<font class=\'bg_info\' onmouseover="land_convert_txt(this,+[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]+)" onmouseout=\'tooltip_hide()\'>(.*)</font>/');

Comment: sorry i am newbee , how to do that?

Comment: [*Please* don't parse HTML with regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Regex to parse HTML with inline Javascript AND `<font>` tags... Ah, the good ol' days. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function extract_regex($subject, $regex, $index = 1)
    {
        preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $matches);
        if (count($matches[$index]))
        {
            if (count($matches[$index]) == 1)
            {
                return trim($matches[$index][0]);
            }
            return $matches[$index];        
        }
        return '';
    }

    $out = extract_regex("<label class='area'><font class='bg_info' onmouseover='land_convert_txt(this,3067)' onmouseout='tooltip_hide()'>3,067 Sq. Ft.</font></label>","/<label class=\'area\'>(.*)<\/label>/i");

        echo "<xmp>". $out . "</xmp>";
```

Comment: thank you but i stated that the number keep changing i.e. 3067

Comment: what do you mean " that the number keep changing"?

Comment: i mean from one page to another its changing , its variable

Comment: Ok, That mean the result that you need from every page as : `<font class='bg_info' onmouseover='land_convert_txt(this,xxxxxx)' onmouseout='tooltip_hide()'>xxxxxxxx </font>`

Comment: <font class='bg_info' onmouseover='land_convert_txt(this,xxxvariablexxxx)' onmouseout='tooltip_hide()'>xxxiwantthisxxxxx </font>

Comment: like this correct?         $article['area'] = extract_regex($html, '/<label class=\'area\'>(.*)<\/label>/i');

Comment: sure that may be right

Comment: but still not getting the text and area

Comment: update changes, that work well with me

Comment: atta, thanks but not working

Comment: you can give me your parameters of  extract_regex() as string not variables ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regex to handle HTML!
Don't try to re-invent the wheel, you will probably create a square.

Try using some PHP web scrappers, like:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/

Use code like so:

```
# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($myHTML);

# get an element representing the area element
//$element =  $html->find('label[class=area]'); 
$element = $html->find(".area")

# Echo it out
echo $element[1]->innertext
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i build all my lib using regex and it will cost lost of time to fix it, the area part is only what i need in reg ex

Comment: The time you'll save on maintenance is worth the time you put in to do it right in the first place.